Using environment variables in nginx configuration
I am having my config file for nginx set with some env variables like this
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${WEB_SERVER_PORT};
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root ${WEB_SERVER_DOCUMENT_ROOT};

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass php:${PHP_PORT};
    }
}

As per docs https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ you can set a default.conf.template file and add it as a volume in the docker-compose file, like this
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
   - ./docker/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates

However I try to run docker-compose up I get the following error
2024/09/04 13:07:44 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in "${WEB_SERVER_PORT}" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
webserver  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in "${WEB_SERVER_PORT}" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2

This is my dockerfile
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    openssl

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Are you setting the environment variables WEB_SERVER_PORT and WEB_SERVER_DOCUMENT_ROOT anywhere?  (You probably don't need to set either of these variables: you should almost listen on the standard HTTP port 80 and not another port, and the document root will be a fixed property of your image.  Neither of these values will ever change at runtime.)

@DavidMaze yes, I am having a .env file which I keep them all, which I specify in my docker-compose file in the nginx service as env_file:             - ./docker/.env This is in a new line obviously, just the format here is messing
